# how to set JAVA_HOME in launch file?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, client-rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to set JAVA_HOME environment variable from `find-java-home.sh` program

http://code.cs.tum.edu/indefero/index.php//p/client-rosjava/source/tree/86a8ff29ecda2204271fd08838a047e5ebcedc72/rosjava/scripts/find-java-home.sh

produces following error

```
Roslaunch got a 'No such file or directory' error while attempting to run:

JAVA_HOME=`rosrun rosjava find-java-home.sh` /home/k-okada/ros/diamondback/knowrob-trunk/json_prolog/bin/json_prolog jsk_semantic_maps __name:=json_prolog __log:=/home/k-okada/.ros/log/240f00c8-a37e-11e0-9734-005056c00001/json_prolog-2.log

Please make sure that all the executables in this command exist and have
executable permission. This is often caused by a bad launch-prefix.
```

but

```
roslaun jsk_semantic_maps example-eng2-map.launch --args /json_prolog | bash
```

works.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10463/how-to-set-java_home-in-launch-file?/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2011-07-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if it is possible to use $() or `` inside roslaunch since it is actually bash syntax and I guess roslaunch just uses python. Instead, I suggest a different solution, something like a wrapper script to run something with JAVA_HOME set correctly. The script could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=$(rosrun rosjava find-java-home.sh)
exec $@
```

Then use it as launch-prefix for your node. If you have it working and want it to be added to the rosjava package, please drop me an email.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-07-16**:
Please have a look at the roslaunch documentation ([www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch)). In short:

**Comment by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on 2011-07-16**:
How would you tell the launch file to execute the script? I guess the question is: How to use the "launch-prefix" for the node. Thanks in advance!